# NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When a user logs into my site, [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) tries to update the field in the user model `current_sign_in_at` with the time. But it's producing this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for Mon, 08 Nov 2010 03:11:01 +0000:DateTime
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:75
```

I've found a couple of resources where people have mentioned this problem. There's an [issue on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/240) with no answer. [This page](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5344) has a solution which works in my development environment, because it involves editing `/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb`, but I need a solution that will also work in my production environment on Heroku. Is there a way I can use my edited version of `/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb` on Heroku? Or is there a better way to deal with the problem?

Here's what I'm using:

```
Rails 3.0.1
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036)
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 irb> Time.now.getlocal
 => Mon Nov 08 15:04:05 +0200 2010
```

but

```
irb>DateTime.now.getlocal
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for Mon, 08 Nov 2010 15:05:16 +0200:DateTime
from (irb):17
```

So, I assume, you need to convert your DateTime object to Time

**Updated**

You can use Ruby mixin technique, something like

```
irb > module DateTimePatch
irb ?>  def get_local
irb ?>    "works!"
irb ?>    end
irb ?>  end
 => nil 
irb > DateTime.send(:include, DateTimePatch)
 => DateTime 
irb2 > DateTime.now.get_local
 => "works!"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's essentially what I've done in my development environment, by changing the relevant method in /lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb to use a Time object. But the problem is I don't know how to use this fix in my production environment, because I don't know how to edit the Ruby library that is being used in Heroku.

Comment: @ben you can use Ruby mixin technique, such as I edited my answer above

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was 2 years ago, but I think I found the clearer explanation about why it behave that way, found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246242/1272973). Just for anyone who probably need more explanations like me.