# Undefined method "getlocal" when displaying created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

i use rails 3.2.6, ruby 1.9.3 with the mongoid gem 3.0.

i want to display the created_at field of a database entry, but get the following error:

```
undefined method `getlocal' for "Wed, 25 Apr 2012 15:04:37 -0400":String
```

here's the rails code:

```
<dt>Erstellt am:</dt><dd><%= @app.created_at %></dd>
```

any advice what's the problem? is there a bugfix? should work in my opinion?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I found your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123683/nomethoderror-undefined-method-getlocal-for-datetime-object).

I hope it helps...

Comment: saw that before, but i don't know how to use it for the created_at variable. any advice?

Comment: try converting it to string `@app.created_at.to_s`

Comment: also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby)

Comment: @Tronic In the console, what does `@app.created_at.class` return? Does  it return this `=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, if not, why is it being stored as something else?

Comment: it's returning DateTime!

Comment: did you got the solution for this??

Comment: nope. the mongoid user group wasn't helpful as well. but i dropped mongoid for now, will roll back to mysql!

Comment: Something with your data could be corrupted. That was my case too, see my previous Q/post : [ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `getlocal' for “2008-02-14T02:20:50Z”:String):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586135/actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-getlocal-for-2008-02-14t02205)

Answer (score 1):

`getlocal` is a method on the **Time** class, so it may be a problem of intermixing object types. The system is expecting the `@app.created_at` to be an instance of Time, **not DateTime**. Make sure the field type for `created_at` is DateTime and that when creating/updating this field, make sure the object you put in is also a DateTime object.

Comment: i use mongoid and it sets the created_at timestamp automatically, so don't know...

Comment: how do I make sure? I tried `field :createdAt, type: DateTime` but it is still crashing

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to your model

```
include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

see http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#timestamps

Answer (score 0):

if you use mongoid, instead of
`@app.created_at`
try
`@app[:created_at]`
this worked for me