# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `getlocal' for "2008-02-14T02:20:50Z":String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mongoid, rvm

After updating Mongoid 3.0.1 / Rails 3.2.6 it start getting a 'getlocal' method error when displaying created_at :

```
Showing /home/lsoave/rails/github/gitwatcher/app/views/shared/_watch-list-table.html.haml where line #28 raised: 

undefined method `getlocal' for "2008-02-14T02:20:50Z":String

Extracted source (around line #28): 

28:           %td= repo.created_at.to_s(:pretty)
```

UPDATE

I've got a config/initializers/time_formats.rb which set that format

```
$ cat config/initializers/time_formats.rb

Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:pretty] = lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a, %b %e at %l:%M") + time.strftime("%p").downcase }
```

anyway the error happen also by simply call `repo.created_at` (omitting .to_s(:pretty))

UPDATE

I just tried a rollback, on RVM/Ruby - Rails - Mongoid stack without success :

```
from ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.6 to ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.2.3

from Mongoid 3.0.1 to Mongoid 2.4.3

from Rails 3.2.6 to Rails 3.2.3
```

see RVM output :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/tests/gitwatcher$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/tests/gitwatcher$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/tests/gitwatcher$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   global
=> rails-3.2.3

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/tests/gitwatcher$
```

... I guest that is something at ENV level at this point, but what ?

Comment: What does your time format for :pretty look like?

Comment: I've got a config/initializers/time_formats.rb which set that format (see the UPDATE)

Comment: I'd keep an eye on this forum, it might be a potential bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongoid/0RgSQyAX34I

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242935/undefined-method-getlocal-when-displaying-created-at

Comment: @Beerlington yeah, a knew those threads but unfurtunatly even after rollbacking Ruby, then Mongoid, then Rails I still get back the same error ( see last UPDATE )

Comment: Maybe something with your data got corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something with your data got corrupt.